# Email domain validation using DNS check in PHP

Tags: php, email, github, dns, filter-validate-email

I'm now more with sending bulk emails using SMTP. Before sending mails I need to check those mail id's are valid. I have got a code to check it & I have added it below. Its from the Github. I just need confirm with you all that by using this DNS port checks, does it makes our server in a trouble like Blacklisting etc.., when checking lots of mails which are not valid?

```
<?php
function verifyEmail($toemail, $fromemail, $getdetails = false){
    $email_arr = explode("@", $toemail);
    $domain = array_slice($email_arr, -1);
    $domain = $domain[0];
    // Trim [ and ] from beginning and end of domain string, respectively
    $domain = ltrim($domain, "[");
    $domain = rtrim($domain, "]");
    if( "IPv6:" == substr($domain, 0, strlen("IPv6:")) ) {
        $domain = substr($domain, strlen("IPv6") + 1);
    }
    $mxhosts = array();
    if( filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) )
        $mx_ip = $domain;
    else
        getmxrr($domain, $mxhosts, $mxweight);
    if(!empty($mxhosts) )
        $mx_ip = $mxhosts[array_search(min($mxweight), $mxhosts)];
    else {
        if( filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) ) {
            $record_a = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_A);
        }
        elseif( filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) ) {
            $record_a = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_AAAA);
        }
        if( !empty($record_a) )
            $mx_ip = $record_a[0]['ip'];
        else {
            $result   = "invalid";
            $details .= "No suitable MX records found.";
            return ( (true == $getdetails) ? array($result, $details) : $result );
        }
    }

    $connect = @fsockopen($mx_ip, 25); 
    if($connect){ 
        if(preg_match("/^220/i", $out = fgets($connect, 1024))){
            fputs ($connect , "HELO $mx_ip\r\n"); 
            $out = fgets ($connect, 1024);
            $details .= $out."\n";

            fputs ($connect , "MAIL FROM: <$fromemail>\r\n"); 
            $from = fgets ($connect, 1024); 
            $details .= $from."\n";
            fputs ($connect , "RCPT TO: <$toemail>\r\n"); 
            $to = fgets ($connect, 1024);
            $details .= $to."\n";
            fputs ($connect , "QUIT"); 
            fclose($connect);
            if(!preg_match("/^250/i", $from) || !preg_match("/^250/i", $to)){
                $result = "invalid"; 
            }
            else{
                $result = "valid";
            }
        } 
    }
    else{
        $result = "invalid";
        $details .= "Could not connect to server";
    }
    if($getdetails){
        return array($result, $details);
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

If you have any better ideas, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

A DNS lookup won't result in blacklisting. However it will be very sensitive to the quality of your DNS service - I've recently started using [net_dns2](https://netdns2.com/documentation/examples/) rather than getmxrr() as the latter does not differentiate between timeouts, NXDOMAIN and other errors (unfortunately the DNS servers here are configured by our "experts").

(it might also be helpful to know that I use the curl_multi_*() functions to run concurrent lookups - processing a large list can take a *long* time - described [here](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html)).

Probing the MX may well result in you being blacklisted - and its mostly a waste of time as measure of deliverability (and as the script you're using explicitly resolves an IP address for each MX, somewhat expensive in terms of performance). Further it will lead to false negatives if the primary MX is unavailable (SMTP is designed to be asynchronous).

An alternative solution, reducing the false negatives (and false positives compared with the method you describe) is to use a [bounce handler](https://github.com/cfortune/PHP-Bounce-Handler), although this comes at the cost of some latency in making a determination.

I'd also suggest (depending on the legth of time it takes to process the list) that you pre-validate the email address with a regex - but **beware** there are a **lot of bad examples** of how to do this on the internet.

Comment: Ty, for the response. I will check it.